# matlab - plot - conversion to double from sym is not possible

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm having some problems with my code. Here is it:

```
syms I t v;
v = t*exp(-t);
I = int(v,t)
t = linspace(0,10);
plot(t, I)
```

When i try to plot, i get ??? Error using ==> plot
Conversion to double from sym is not possible.
I tried many ways but it doesn't work.
I'm new to matlab so I don't know much. Hope to get help from everybody. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

because `I` is a symbolic expression the correct plotting function is :

```
fplot(I,[0 10])
```

Alternatively you can create from `I` an anonymous function (say `It`), and then use the `t` you had as an input to `It` :

```
It = matlabFunction(I);
plot(t, It(t))
```

Comment: i did as your way but it still dosen't work. However, i used ezplot and it worked. Anyway thank you very much.